# How can i preserve flv custom metadata when using ffmpeg

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, flv, flash-media-server

I have a FMS flv (video/audio stream) which I created and I inserted custom metadata into flv. I able to test this flv file with a simple flash player that reads the metadata coming from the flv (which I inserted when I created flv on FMS).
 When I try and use ffmpeg to convert or just copy flv (even to another flv) I am not seeing my dynamic custom metadata (I do see some static metadata flv has in header). It is unclear if this is doable (using ffmpeg 1.1) as soon as I do any thing with ffmpeg (even a copy) this custom metadata is gone. I was expecting a simple flv to flv would work but so far no.

is this possible? - one example I've tried (of many) is

```
ffmpeg -i meta09.flv -map_metadata 0 -c copy out4.flv
```